# Standard queue package for Haskell?

Tags: haskell, queue

Is there a standard queue implementation for Haskell? I see several reasonably mature priority queue implementations, but no simple queues. Data.Sequence seems OK, but I assume we could get better performance with a more restricted datatype. Further, restricting the operations (ie, not a deque) can prevent bugs from dequeuing from the wrong end.

Edit:

To clarify, I was hoping for a mature Haskell implementation, preferably in Haskell Platform or Hackage.

Comment: Although thoroughly off-topic for StackOverflow, this is an excellent question. You can indeed get much better performance from more restricted types. The simple "banker's queue" behzad.nouri suggests is very good when the queue is not too big. Once you push up against the cache size, it starts to look pretty bad. You might want to consider fancy cache-oblivious queues if performance is critical. Otherwise, I would *guess* you might do all right with Okasaki's finger-tree-style "implicit queues".

Comment: I don't think it is off-topic as I am not looking for a subjective comparison; I  want to know if I missed something obvious in my search (eg, for C++ the answer would be std::queue). It may be that the best answer is just Data.Sequence, or "no, such a packages does not exist." I updated my question to be more objective.

Comment: There are lots of kinds of queues with different performance characteristics, capabilities, etc. Are you looking for a persistent queue? A monadic ephemeral queue? A queue occasionally used persistently? A queue for communication between concurrent threads?

Comment: Yes, a persistent queue. I found the answer in GHC release notes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data.Queue was added to `base` in ghc 6.4 [1] and deprecated in ghc 6.6 [2] when it was subsumed by `Data.Sequence`.

From the 6.6 release notes:

> There is a new module Data.Sequence for finite sequences. The Data.Queue module is now deprecated in favour of this faster, more featureful replacement.

[1] https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.4/docs/html/users_guide/release-6-4.html

[2] https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.6/docs/html/users_guide/release-6-6.html

Comment: `Data.Sequence` is lots of fun when you need lots of reasonably efficient operations (I'm currently the person primarily responsible for maintaining it, so I have a pretty decent sense of its good and bad features). But you'll pretty much always do better by using a less flexible structure if you can get away with it. `Data.Sequence` has to maintain size annotations to support splitting, needs to support multiple internal node sizes and extra "digit" sizes to support concatenation, etc.

Comment: If you make only light use of persistence, you may be better off with larger nodes. If you're storing unboxable types, you may be able to use unboxed vectors in a tree to make things really scream. There's no one queue to rule them all.

Comment: Thank you for the advise; I will keep it in mind if/when I run into performance issues. That said, it is good to know `Data.Sequence` is reasonable for general use as not writing & debugging a custom queue is likely to save me more time than the efficiency costs (and as you pointed out in your comment on behzad.nouri's answer, it is easy to make subtle mistakes that greatly decrease efficiency).

Comment: @dfeuer Any hope that index-based insert and delete will be added?
https://github.com/haskell/containers/issues/138

Comment: @Alan, I have to think some more about that; I forgot I'd had that idea. I'm not sure it's possible to do better than splitting and re-joining, and I'm generally hesitant to add new functions that can be implemented as efficiently using the existing API in an obvious way.

Comment: @dfeuer If that is really the best that can be done (for now at least), the documentation should imo mention that.  Otherwise an API oversight may be suspected.

Comment: @dfeuer One other thing: might there be possible gains from an analog to `Data.Array.//`?

Comment: @Alan, actually, I've just had an idea for `insert` that I'm working up right now, using 2-3 (non-finger) tree insertion. I don't know if it will work out, and I don't know if it will be fast, but I'll give it a go. `//` for sequences is possible, but to do it reasonably efficiently I think we'd need to rearrange some module dependencies so it could use `Data.IntMap`. The coming major version of `containers` will not do any such large-scale restructuring, but some ideas are very definitely in the air for doing so in the version after that.

Comment: @Alan, I opened https://github.com/haskell/containers/issues/262 for `//`, but you should also email libraries@haskell.org with a formal proposal.

Comment: @Alan, for StackOverflow posterity, know that the next version `Data.Sequence` will offer `insertAt` and `deleteAt`, each of which is several times faster than splitting and re-joining.

Answer (score 5):

Okasaki in his book [Purely Functional Data Structures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521663504), describes a FIFO queue as a pair of lists, *front* and *back*, where the front list contains the front elements of the queue in the correct order, and the back list contains the rear elements of the queue in the *reverse* order.

```
data Queue a = Queue [a] [a]  -- front & back lists
```

The idea is that new items are inserted to *front* of the *back* list, whereas values are popped out from the front list. If the front list becomes empty it is replaced by the *reverse* of the back list.

The queue maintains the invariance that the front list can be empty only if the back list is also empty; and performs amortized O(1).

```
-- helper function to maintain the invariance:
-- front list can be empty only if the back list is also empty
fill :: Queue a -> Queue a
fill (Queue [] b) = Queue (reverse b) []
fill q = q

push :: a -> Queue a -> Queue a
push x (Queue f b) = fill $ Queue f (x:b)

front :: Queue a -> Maybe a
front (Queue (x:_) _) = Just x
front _               = Nothing

pop :: Queue a -> Maybe (Queue a)
pop (Queue (_:xs) b) = Just . fill $ Queue xs b
pop _                = Nothing
```

Comment: Sure, but I was looking for a mature Haskell implementation, preferably in Haskell Platform or Hackage.

Comment: That version of the queue is not the banker's queue I thought it was. Your queue can perform very badly when used persistently.

Comment: @dfeuer ...but, to be fair, a *persistent* queue is a pretty niche need.