# Functional queue type

Tags: haskell, data-structures, types, f#, functional-programming

I would like to represent a kind of queue data structure functionally, but I haven't really gotten anywhere. I've looked into Zippers but they don't seem to be the right structure.

Specifically, I'm trying to represent a series of delay lines (for audio effects like echo or reverb), so the functionality needed is as follows:

1. Append data to the front
2. Remove the last item (can just be thrown away)

For my particular use, these two operations would be used in conjunction as to keep the queue a constant size, but this constraint is not fundamental. I could just use a list, but I'm thinking there's got to be something cleaner than that. What is the best way to represent this type?

I'm using F#, but any language is welcome.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [`Data.Sequence`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html)

Comment: @chi How does it work? I guess I poorly phrased that last part, in that I'd like to use this thing in F#, but I don't have much of an idea of how Data.Sequence is actually defined. It looks like the operations are pretty close to what I want though.

Comment: @Jwosty If you want to look at the implementation, you can click on the "source" button on the side and it will take you to it: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/src/Data.Sequence.html

Comment: I think a list is really what you want to use. Take a look at [this Programmers.SE post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/222316/is-there-any-particular-reason-for-the-use-of-lists-over-queues-in-functional-pr) discussing this topic more.

Comment: @jkeuhlen Thanks. I was hoping that there'd be a nice type of queue, but I've been using just a plain list so far. Looks like lists it is!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37505725

Comment: @Jwosty The associated algorithm is described in the paper linked at the beginning in the documentation. It is a non-trivial result to achieve a good performance without mutability, in a functional way.

Answer (score 11):

By functional I assume you mean an immutable queue?

If you use F# and .NET there are for example:

- [ImmutableQueue<>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467186(v=vs.111).aspx)
- [FSharpX.Collections.Queue<>](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Collections/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Collections/Queue.fsi)

If you like to read on how to implement a functional queue I recommend [Purely Functional Data Structures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521663504) by Chris Okasaki.

One of the first ways Okasaki implements a functional queue is using two `List<>`, one you pop from and one you push to. When the pop list is empty the push queue is reversed and becomes the pop list.

Bear in mind this is in many ways a rather inefficient queue but it's also rather simple:

```ml
type Queue<'T> = 'T list*'T list

let empty<'T> : Queue<'T> = [], []

let isEmpty ((f, r) : Queue<'T>) : bool =
  match f, r with
  | []    , []  -> true
  | _     , _   -> false

let headAndTail ((f, r) : Queue<'T>) : 'T*Queue<'T> =
  match f, r with
  | []    , []  -> failwith "Queue is empty"
  | v::vs , r   -> v, (vs, r)
  | _     , r   -> let v::vs = List.rev r in v, (vs, [])

let snoc ((f, r) : Queue<'T>) (v : 'T) : Queue<'T> = (f, v::r)

let fold (f : 'S -> 'T -> 'S) (s : 'S) (q : Queue<'T>) : 'S =
  let rec loop ss qq =
    if isEmpty qq then ss
    else
      let hh, tt = headAndTail qq
      loop (f ss hh) tt
  loop s q

let ofArray (vs : 'T []) : Queue<'T> = vs |> Array.fold snoc empty

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
  let q = [| 1..20 |] |> ofArray
  fold (fun _ v -> printfn "%A" v) () q
  0
```

Comment: I wouldn't say this is inefficient. All the operations are amortized O(1), as demonstrated in the book you recommend. There is an occasional expensive `reverse` operation, but those are proven to be rare enough that your average time is low.

Comment: I like this. Thanks!

Comment: Okasaki queue maintains the _invariance_ that the front list can be empty only if the back list is also empty and uses this invariance in his amortized performance analysis. (see `fill` function in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37505858/625914)). You are violating this invariance.